# Wordpress Posts - Display Child Post as Subtitle

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, while-loop

I am trying to list all of the posts from a custom post type on a page which I have got working but what I am trying to do is list any child post as a subtitle of it's parent rather that a title on it's own.

Here is what I have:

```
$post_loop = new WP_Query( $post_args );
while ( $post_loop->have_posts() ) : $post_loop->the_post();
    global $post;
    $pod = pods($postname, $post->ID);
    ?>
      <div class="resource-innner">
        <div class="resource-innner-title"><h2><?php echo the_title( ); ?></h2></div>
        <!-- ID of each element is $post->ID -->
        <!-- I can use $post->post_parent to see the ID of the parent post for each child -->
        <!-- ONLY SHOWS THIS IS A CHILD IS LINKED TO THE PARENT ABOVE -->
        <div class="resource-innner-subtitle"><h3><?php echo the_title( ); ?></h3></div>
      </div> 
      <br /><br />
    <?php
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
```

I'm kinda stuck on where to start, started thinking of foreach etc but couldn't figure out how I would get it to display as a subtitle and exclude it as a title

Comment: Posts don't have hierarchical structure, meaning there is no parent child relationship between them.

Comment: Hi @Ruvee, I have used PODs and within that you can apply Hierarchy. It seems to work as child post contains the parents ID in an array under `$post->post_parent`.